# C# Collection with class inheritance and generic type inheritance does not allow to add inherited class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I encounter something maybe possible, but does not work.

Here is sample class,

```
abstract class BaseModel { }

abstract class BaseViewModel<T> where T : BaseModel
{
    protected T model;
}

class ModelA : BaseModel { }

class ViewModelA : BaseViewModel<ModelA> { }
```

and now I try to do

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var collection = new List<BaseViewModel<BaseModel>>();
        collection.Add(new ViewModelA());
    }
}
```

Intuitively, it looks to be work. However it does not possible to add `ViewModelA`.

I want to know why this is not possible, and work around of this situation.

Comment: A `BaseViewModel<BaseModel>` must be able to handle anything that inherits from `BaseModel`. You are passing it a `ViewModelA`, which can only handle a subset of things that inherit from `BaseModel`, i.e. objects that inehrit from `ModelA`. So the assignment is not allowed.

Comment: @JohnWu then is there any work around?

Comment: the workaround is: rethink your design. Is your list **really** of the base-type or do all your entitites are allways of the derived type? What is your cinsuming code that uses the collection?

Comment: Imagine this **would be** possible. Then users of your code could also write `collection.Add(AnotherViewModel)`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I am trying to allow `collection.Add(AnotherViewModel)` with the restriction to inherit `BaseViewModel<T> where T : BaseModel`. I understand it could be a design problem but I was curious why it does not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewModelA` is not equal to `BaseViewModel<BaseModel>` even though you may think it is

This is because classes are invariant.

- ***Invariance*** : means that you can use only the *type* originally specified
- ***Covariance*** : enables you to use a more *derived type* than originally specified.

One way to achieve what you want (potentially) is to use a *covariant interface parameter* via the [out generic modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier). However, it has certain limitations. *Type parameters* can only be used as a *return type* of *interface methods* and not used as a type of *method arguments*

**Example**

```
public interface IBaseViewModel<out T>  where T : BaseModel 
{ 
   ... 
}

abstract class BaseViewModel<T> : IBaseViewModel<T> where T : BaseModel 
{
   protected T model; 
}

class ModelA : BaseModel { }

class ViewModelA : BaseViewModel<ModelA> { }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var collection = new List<IBaseViewModel<BaseModel>>();
   collection.Add(new ViewModelA()); // this now works
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have different theory in simple words about your implementation, As per your implementation both your `BaseViewModel<T>` and `BaseModel`  are abstract which mean you cannot instance an abstract class, meaning you cannot use `BaseViewModel<BaseModel> baseModel = new ViewModelA();`. When you adding to the collection you are trying to create an instance for the abstract class which violates the abstract class rules. I have modified your a little bit so that you can add to the collection.

```
abstract class BaseModel { }

abstract class BaseViewModel<T> where T : BaseModel
{
     protected T model;
}

class ModelA : BaseModel { }

class ViewModelA : BaseViewModel<ModelA> { }

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var collection = new List<BaseViewModel<ModelA>>();
    collection.Add(new ViewModelA());
}
```

You can also make interface as per the previous answers to make decoupled class.

Comment: Thanks you helped me to understand this situation better, however if make collection to `List<BaseViewModel<ModelA>>`, I can not add `ViewModelB : BaseViewModel<ModelB>` to collection.

Comment: Obviously you cannot `ViewModelB: BaseViewModel<ModelB>` to the collection which takes an instance of `BaseViewModel<ModelA>` as the generic type is binded to `ModelA`. What you could do is that you can create an interface which is inherited in both `ModelA` and `ModelB` and then `List<BaseViewModel<YourInterface>>`. Then you can add any object which inherits the interface, refer to the previous answer posted by @Michael Randall